# HoloLens - Capturing photo when locatable camera is in VideoMode (streaming)

Tags: c#, .net, webcam, hololens

I am trying to create a HoloLens application, which uses the built in WebCam to take photos and sends them to a rest interface for further face recognition. This is working well so far. To capture photos from the WebCam it needs to be in the *PhotoMode*.

**The problem:**
If I want now to present my application via live stream, the WebCam is set automatically to the *VideoMode* and capturing photos is not possible. 
The locatable camera description https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/locatable_camera_in_unity says:

> "Only a single operation can occur with the camera at a time."

Since the application has to be presented to a great number of people it is absolutely essential to show it via live stream.

Does somebody have any general idea how to solve this problem, or maybe some hack to access the WebCam in *PhotoMode* simultaneously to the streaming?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Corresponding question on the HoloLens forum: https://forums.hololens.com/discussion/7574/hololens-capturing-photo-when-locatable-camera-is-in-videomode-streaming

Comment: I doubt you can do what you want exactly due to hardware. Sorry for simplistic solution but can you not just stream some blank image while shutting down video mode, take your photo in photo mode then resume streaming in video mode?

Comment: I can try it, but will it not break my streaming connection, if I interfere it? And to be honest I am absolutely clueless how to "stream some blank image" from the code in HoloLens...

Comment: Hmm I thought you coded your own video streaming. My solution is void then.

Comment: Thanks anyway...

Answer (score 0):

This is possible if you can live with Preview Frames from the MediaCapture streams. Just start the video capture (layer on holograms if you need to), and then use the PreviewFrames as your 'photos'. This limits you to the resolution of the camera stream of course.

I was able to get this plugin working on a HoloLens. Had to use .Net instead of IL2CPP and I used 2017.4.22f1. At the very least the code shows how use MediaCapture and PreviewFrames to get a video feed from the camera for which you can grab the current frame to save as a photo. The sample doesn't do that last bit, but the bytes for the frames are being passed around, just need to make them available for your need. =)

https://github.com/VulcanTechnologies/HoloLensCameraStream